# Introduce a new line before every row containing a specific word in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, newline

I am new to linux. I have tab delim text file like following

```
A1 title body.1 gene
A1 head head.1  head
A1 trunk trunk.1 trunk
A1 tail tail.1 tail
A2 title body.2 gene
A2 head head.2 head
A2 trunk trunk.2 trunk
A2 tail tail.2 tail
A3 title body.3 gene
A3 head head.3 head
A3 trunk trunk.3 trunk
A4 title title.4 gene
A4 trunk trunk.4 trunk
A4 tail tail.4 tail
```

I would like introduce a new line before every row containing the word "gene" in the last column like following:

```
A1 title body.1 gene
A1 head head.1  head
A1 trunk trunk.1 trunk
A1 tail tail.1 tail

A2 title body.2 gene
A2 head head.2 head
A2 trunk trunk.2 trunk
A2 tail tail.2 tail

A3 title body.3 gene
A3 head head.3 head
A3 trunk trunk.3 trunk

A4 title title.4 gene
A4 trunk trunk.4 trunk
A4 tail tail.4 tail
```

I tried the following command

```
sed 's/gene/\
\n&\g' file.txt
```

but it introduces a new line just after row containing word "gene".

It would be great if any one could guide me how to introduce a new line before very row containing a word "`gene`" in the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this (extended regex syntax):

```
$ sed -r 's/(^.*?\tgene$)/\n\1/' example

A1  title   body.1  gene
A1  head    head.1  head
A1  trunk   trunk.1 trunk
A1  tail    tail.1  tail

A2  title   body.2  gene
A2  head    head.2  head
A2  trunk   trunk.2 trunk
A2  tail    tail.2  tail

A3  title   body.3  gene
A3  head    head.3  head
A3  trunk   trunk.3 trunk

A4  title   title.4 gene
A4  trunk   trunk.4 trunk
A4  tail    tail.4  tail
```

In this regex you can see:

1. a substitution command `'s/.../.../'`
2. capture group of a whole line which ends with a tab character and gene: `(^.*?\tgene$)`.
3. inserting a newline character and previously captured group (first and only) to the result: `\n\1`

Please note there is a catch in your question:

> I would like introduce a new line before every row containing word
>   "gene" in the last column

This leads to an assumption you need your result's first line to be empty (or a single newline to be precise)

However your example's first line clearly is not preceded with an empty line.
If this is really what you need, you should use sed addressing:

```
pono@pono-carbon:~$ sed -r '2,$s/(^.*?\tgene$)/\n\1/' example
A1  title   body.1  gene
A1  head    head.1  head
A1  trunk   trunk.1 trunk
A1  tail    tail.1  tail

A2  title   body.2  gene
A2  head    head.2  head
A2  trunk   trunk.2 trunk
A2  tail    tail.2  tail

A3  title   body.3  gene
A3  head    head.3  head
A3  trunk   trunk.3 trunk

A4  title   title.4 gene
A4  trunk   trunk.4 trunk
A4  tail    tail.4  tail
```

Answer (score 1):

Using backreferences

```
sed 's/\(^.*gene\)/\n\1/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Your command separated the every row containing the word "'gene'" and the word "'gene'" by a new line which is different from my expected output.

Comment: This is not what you expected? On my computer this line (sed...) gives the exact same output as in your example. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the last field is `gene`. If so, print an empty line:

```
awk '$NF=="gene" {print ""}1' file
```

this returns:

```
$ awk '$NF=="gene" {print ""}1' file

A1 title body.1 gene
A1 head head.1  head
A1 trunk trunk.1 trunk
A1 tail tail.1 tail

A2 title body.2 gene
A2 head head.2 head
A2 trunk trunk.2 trunk
A2 tail tail.2 tail

A3 title body.3 gene
A3 head head.3 head
A3 trunk trunk.3 trunk

A4 title title.4 gene
A4 trunk trunk.4 trunk
A4 tail tail.4 tail
```

Answer (score 0):

with sed you can use the insert command i:

```
sed '2,${/[\t ]gene$/i\

;}' file
```

the `2,$` condition is used to prevent to add a leading newline at the beginning.